# read string array into an object array

Tags: java, arrays, object

im trying to read a file into an array and then that array into an object class but it only seems to read the first line multiple  times over.

```java
String[] clothesFile = null;
Clothes[] clothes = new Clothes[2000];

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("clothes.csv"));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    assets = line.split(",");

    name = clothes[0];
    style = clothes[1];
    colour = clothes[2];
    brand = clothes[3];
}

for (int ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
    clothes[ii] = new Clothes(name, style, colour, brand);
}

System.out.println("Clothes: ");
for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
    System.out.print(ii + 1 + ". ");
    System.out.print(clothes[ii]);
}
```

when i print the clothes array out, it only prints the first line 10 times so i assume it has created a new object correctly. is it something to do with the loops ive mixed up? thank you

Comment: You need to add your clothes to your array as it's going through the lines, not after. You're currently just overriding the name, style, colour, and brand variables without storing them until after you've gone through every line so you only retain the last override.

Comment: I believe `name = clothes[0];` line should be `name = assets[0];`

Comment: @MNEMO whoops, my real code is assets and its for 16 different variables but i didn't want to post original code/ it would be far too long haha must've missed that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading every line, but only carrying the last line's data through to the next step and reusing it over and over in the next `for` loop.

Instead, create and save a `Clothes` object every time you read a line, something like:

```
int ii = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    assets = line.split(",");

    name = clothes[0];
    style = clothes[1];
    colour = clothes[2];
    brand = clothes[3];
    clothes[ii++] = new Clothes(name, style, colour, brand);
}
```

Comment: You should check `if(clothes.length == 4) { }` to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash there are many improvements that can be made, but this is the smallest change that will get OP moving.

Comment: I agree with you. Unluckily, I have been downvoted on a few occasions even for such a small thing .

Answer (score -1):

Try reading the file this way:

Declare your file's name:

```
public static final String FILE = "location/file.txt";
```

To read the file you have 3 methods.
The first one calls the others.

```
public ObjectList readObjects() throws FileNotFoundException {
        return readObjects(FILE);
    }
```

Second:

```
private ObjectList readObjects(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return lerTarefas(new File(file));
    }
```

Third that reads the file:

```
private ObjectList readObjects(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
            ObjectList objectList = new Object();
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String[] line = in.nextLine().trim().split(";");
                Object object = new Object(line[0].trim(), line[1].trim(), line[2].trim(), line[3].trim(),
                        Integer.parseInt(line[4].trim()), Double.parseDouble(line[5].trim()));
                if (!objectList.contains(object)) {
                    objectList.addObject(object);
                }
            }
            return objectList;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found!");
        }
    }
```

Try this. Then you just got to code a `.toString()` that prints the objects information.

Comment: appreciate it but that it way more complicated than what i have/need

Comment: No problem, I'll leave it here anyway because it can help you in the future.